# Redux creating an object inside of an array of objects within another object. "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, redux, django-rest-framework

I am using react to create a world.  I then use redux to save that world to global state in order to add a country to the world.  I then use that country data to create a city inside of the country object.  The issue that I am having is that I get an error when trying to add a city immediately after creating a country.  The country is showing up in the redux devtools.  And if I reload the page I can create a city assigned to that country without issue.

Redux slice

```js
addCityToCreatedWorld: (state, action) => {
  const { countryPk, newCity } = action.payload;
  const countryIndex = state.createdWorld.countries.findIndex(
    (country) => country.pk === countryPk
  );
  if (countryIndex >= 0) {
    state.createdWorld.countries[countryIndex].cities.push(newCity);
  }
```

React Component

```js
const handleCitySubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const data = {};
  data.name = cityName;
  data.picture = cityPicture;
  data.description = cityDescription;
  data.country = countryData.pk;

  let cityUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST}/api/cities`;
  let cityFetchConfig = {
    method: "post",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  const response = await fetch(cityUrl, cityFetchConfig);
  if (response.ok) {
    const createdCity = await response.json();
    dispatch(
      addCityToCreatedWorld({
        countryPk: countryData.pk,
        newCity: createdCity,
      })
    );
    setSubmitted(true);
  } else {
    console.error(response);
  }
```

I have console logged the data being passed into the slice.  I have console logged the data in the slice and have checked the redux dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`state.createdWorld.countries[countryIndex].cites` is undefined, so there's no array to `push` elements into. In the reducer case first grab the matched country by searching state, then check if there is a `cities` array and create it if necessary.

```js
addCityToCreatedWorld: (state, action) => {
  const { countryPk, newCity } = action.payload;

  const country = state.createdWorld.countries.find(
    (country) => country.pk === countryPk
  );

  if (country) {
    if (!country.cities) {
      country.cities = [];
    }

    country.cities.push(newCity);
  }
},
```

Better would be to add the `cities` array when the country is added to state in *its* reducer case.

Example:

```js
addCountryToCreatedWorld: (state, action) => {
  const { country } = action.payload;

  state.createdWorld.countries.push({
    ...country,
    cities: [],
  });
},
addCityToCreatedWorld: (state, action) => {
  const { countryPk, newCity } = action.payload;

  state.createdWorld.countries.find(
    (country) => country.pk === countryPk
  )?.cities.push(newCity);
},
```

Comment: Thank You, I'm assuming it's always better practice to handle things in the reducer instead of the api call then?  I'm still getting the hang of redux and rtk query is my next goal.

Comment: @slap26 Yes, I'd consider using the reducer function to handle all state update logic to be a best practice. By centralizing the logic to the reducer functions you have more determinant state updates. You're not counting on the code dispatching the actions to have correctly injected some "state" if it's missing. You can use the reducer functions to maintain a state invariant.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an empty array of cities to the initial created  country

```js
if (response.ok) {
    const createdCountry = await response.json();
    createdCountry.cities = [];
}
```